# reportNG does not generate the test-ouput foler

Tags: testng-eclipse, reportng

I am using the testNG that with reportNG plugin for the test result.
In eclipse testNG setting, I was disable the testNG report as the default listeners and added reportNG.

When I right click the project and run as testNG, i could see the test-output/html folder created with test result in it.
But this should use the default testng.xml.

If I create the testng.xml manually and right click on it, select run as testNG suite, i could see the running passed, but cannot find test-output/html folder generated.

Can anyone tell me what is the reason, where to configure this, i guess this may just some issue with the testNG setting, but now sure where.

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opps. I tried to add the

```
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />
  </listeners>
```

into the testng.xml that i created manually. Now works.